# Type inference for polymorphic recursive functions

Tags: haskell, recursion, polymorphism

The [Polymorphic recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion#Nested_datatypes) page on Wikipedia gives following example where Haskell's type checker fails to infer type without explicit type annotation:

```
data Nested a = a :<: (Nested [a]) | Epsilon

length Epsilon    = 0
length (_ :<: xs) = 1 + length xs
```

When compiling this code, GHC says:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
Expected type: Nested t
  Actual type: Nested [t]
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: Nested [t]
  length :: Nested t -> a
```

I understand how `t` becomes `[t]`, but I don't see why it is a problem for a typechecker. If we let `length` be `Nested t -> a` and then stumbled upon `length xs` and let it be `Nested [t] -> b`, why can't we assume that `a ~ b` and successfully typecheck this? Or the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: The problem is, as far as I know, that for a fixed `a` you're trying to use `length :: Nested a -> Int` (1st inferred) and `length :: Nested [a] -> Int` (2nd inferred) in the same context. Due to the second inferred type, the type checker will then set length's overall type to `length :: Nested [a] -> Int`, which again updates the inner type to `length :: Nested [[a]] -> Int`; a change on the outer type gets reflected on the inner one. The type checker gives up, since the substitution `a ~ [a]` would never end.

Comment: Type inference does not generalize type variables until the recursion is completely handled. IOW, it searches for a _monotype_ `t` such that, assuming all the recursive occurrences have type `t`, the whole function body has type `t`. After that, roughly, all the variables in `t` get `forall`-generalized. Inferring polytypes in the first phase is, IIRC, undecidable, so some compromise is needed to achieve something useful in practice.

Comment: The other comments explain why it would be difficult or impossible to implement this, but I also don't think it would be particularly desirable. Polymorphic recursion tends to be confusing even *with* type signatures. Without them ... I don't even want to think about it. I'd be likely to write the signatures first and use typed holes to work out the terms.

Comment: [Type inference for polymorphic recursion is equivalent to semi-unification and therefore undecidable and requires the use of a semi-algorithm or programmer supplied type annotations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion)

Comment: Is there any GHC extension(s) that would make this code typecheck? If they are, do they make typechecking a possibly non-terminating procedure?

Comment: @arrowd No extension necessary. Just put a type signature on it.

Comment: @Carl I meant, is there extension that would make typechecker infer the type even without explicit signature.

Comment: @arrowd No. Inferring polymorphic recursion is undecidable. Checking it is easy.

Comment: @Carl It is undecidable in general. Does that mean that types can't be inferred for any (and this particular) polymorphic recursive function?

Comment: @arrowd You could add some complex heuristics to cover some small portion of cases. Or you could just say "put a type signature on it, and it all just works".  The latter seems like a much better use of everyone's time.  Do you really want to debug why the heuristics didn't let it infer in your case as a user of GHC?

Comment: @Carl, if someone wants to write such a heuristic, it could potentially be used to improve GHC's type errors in some cases.